# Webpage unavailable for JESS Engine

Tags: jess

http://www.jessrules.com/
and
https://herzberg.ca.sandia.gov/
Do not work any more.

How can I get a copy and an academic license for the engine ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get a specially licensed version of Jess 61p4 for use with the book Jess in Action from https://www.manning.com/books/jess-in-action.

Answer (score 0):

SO's jess tag has been absolutely quiet for several months. My last download from the Jess page is from May 2018. Usually Ernest Friedman-Hill from Sandia responds within 24 hours, workdays. The weekend is coming up, so be patient.