# Where to access Jess Rules engine software

Tags: rule-engine, jess

I am interested in trying out Jess Rules, but I am not able to access the web site. Both [jess.sandia.gov](http://jess.sandia.gov) and [herzberg.ca.sandia.gov](http://herzberg.ca.sandia.gov/jess/) sites are down currently. I am unable to locate the new location if it has moved. Any help appreciated.

Comment: See the question Webpage unavailable for JESS Engine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714652/webpage-unavailable-for-jess-engine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpage unavailable for JESS Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714652/webpage-unavailable-for-jess-engine)

Comment: I would say based on lack of any response from the Jess Rules team and no active site, this software is quite dead.

Answer (score 0):

Jess is a programmer's library written in Java. Therefore, to use Jess, you'll need a Java Virtual Machine (JVM). You can get an excellent JVM for Windows, Linux, and Solaris free from Sun Microsystems. Jess 7 is compatible with all released versions of Java starting with JDK 1.4, including JDK 1.5, the latest release. Older Jess versions numbered 4.x were compatible with JDK 1.0, 5.x versions worked with JDK 1.1, and Jess 6 worked with JDK 1.2 and up.

Be sure your JVM is installed and working correctly before trying to use Jess.

To use the Jess DE integrated development environment, you'll need version 3.1 or later of the Eclipse SDK from http://www.eclipse.org. Be sure that Eclipse is installed and working properly before installing the Jess DE.

Check out these two sites:
https://www.manning.com/books/jess-in-action
https://synotix.home.xs4all.nl/robbieng/docs/jess43doc.html